# Should large-scale data be uploaded to GitHub?

Tags: github

I'm working on an image recognition problem with training and testing datasets being about 1 GB in total. Normally I would track all relevant files with git and put them on GitHub, but considering the dataset size, this might be not the best choice.

What are the recommended approaches in such situations? Should the data be just part of .gitignore?

Additional question: is it possible in Python notebook to open a connection to a specific Kaggle dataset and use it for modelling?